# How to create polygons from enclosed polylines

Tags: python

I have a set of polylines that intersect and form enclosed areas. Is there any good way in Python of getting the coordinates for each point of the lines that forms a given polygon or to somehow convert enclosed areas into polygons?

Comment: what library are you using for polylines?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with "shapely" I think it's a good library to work with polygons and lines.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

x = Polygon ( [[0,2], [1,1], [2,3]]) 
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

x = Polygon ( [[0,2], [1,1], [2,3]]) #1st polyline
y = Polygon ( [[0,1], [1,4], [2,1]]) #1st polyline


intersec = x.intersection(y)
boundaryCoords = list (intersec.boundary.coords) #as list of tuple
boundaryCoords = np.asarray(intersec.boundary.coords) #as numpy array
print(boundaryCoords)
```

Comment: Shapely was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Markus1991 I'm curious in what are you working. I discovered Shapely some weeks ago and simplified a lot of my work, it's a great library but i'm still learning it

Comment: Worked nicely thanks. One caution, if your polygons overlap more than once, you'll create intersec as a multipolygon (instead of a polygon) and then the above fails with the error "Multi-part geometries do not provide a coordinate sequence". You can extract individual unions using intersec.geoms[0 ]